# Leopard gecko tail injury question (harsh pictures)

Tags: reptiles, injury, leopard-geckos, anatomy, autotomy

My little buddy ran away from me yesterday and ran next to a little statue of the Statue of Liberty and it fell and hit his tail. He dropped the tail and that was a clean snap. There's this bit left over that has the same little fleshy pieces as were on the end of the tail. This doesn't go around and it looks like just a part is open.

My question is, do I need to worry about necrosis? He doesn't have a sandy substrate. Currently it's sterile paper towel but I'm just being overly cautious. No discharge or bleeding. The drop happened last night (January 1st, 2019).

[image] [image]

Comment: I don't know anything substancial about reptile physiology, but the dark spots worry me. They could indicade clotted blood (like a hematoma) or necrosis. If in doubt, always consult a vet as soon as possible.

Comment: you need to ask a vet about this it needs to be treated,i do not know anything about reptiles but i do know the loss of a limb needs veterinary care no matter what type of animal it is.

Comment: @trond not necessarily dropping a tail is a defense mechanism. Usually it happens and it's all fine and dandy. Just this little guys stump looks odd.

Comment: How did everything turn out with you leopard gecko's tail? I have one in a similar situation. Please let us know. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can see right away this is most likely infected. If this is the case, you should consider getting your leopard gecko checked out by a local vet, whether a herp vet or just your veterinarian.

It looks like a blood clot but if it wasn’t bleeding at all then it’s unlikely. I would keep him on sterile paper towels and keep an eye on it so things don’t get out of hand.

Make sure you give him/her a wash **with distilled water**. I don’t think you have to worry about necrosis if you keep a close eye on it and give him/her a bath every other day. Good luck to you and your gecko.

Comment: I don't think it's infected, as of today it looks clean and I'll give him a bath tonight. His split is tucking under the secondary rip so I think it will scab and pop off when it starts to regrow. I'm gonna give him a few days to see how it looks. Our local vet charges an arm and a leg. He's eating better today which is great. Poor guy also she'd his whole skin last night . He can't catch a break. I appreciate the advice